# Collation conflict with temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

The collation of tempdb is `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`. The collation of the database is also `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`. Yet the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM ##CitiesMapping AS cm
INNER JOIN Cities ON cm.CityName=Cities.Name
```

returns:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_100_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.
```

The server default collation is also `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`

Comment: What SQL Server version do you use? Can you double check default collation for the instance of SQL Server you use?

Comment: @Serg `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` - updated answer

Comment: take a look at collation of `Cities.Name` column since single column's collation could be different from general table and database collation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the tables involved as well:

```
SELECT name, collation_name, OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) IN ('Cities')
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the collation is set differently for a single column. The query from Stuart will show you that.  If they are different collations you can specify the collation being used on either side of the comparison like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ##CitiesMapping AS cm
 INNER JOIN Cities 
    ON cm.CityName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = Cities.Name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT;
```

I hope this helps you out.